How to remove mouseover link in taggedpdf - lualatex
I want to use cross-links for sections, figures, tables, etc. by using the \href command. However, when mouseover the link, I get a dialog box like Go to destination section 1.1 in the PDF. This happens when I use the \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}} command for accessibility purposes. Please advise how to remove the dialog box if I mouse over the cross link in the PDF.
I am using LuaLaTeX compiler
My MWE below,
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{A head}\label{sec1}

Normal Para Text see section~\ref{sec1}

\end{document}

Mouseover tooltip like below


Isn't the tooltip a functionality of the PDF viewer? With Okular, for instance, the tooltip is "Go to page 1", both with and without \DocumentMetadata.

do you not get a tooltip at all in your viewer without \DocumentMetadata? I'm so used to seeing this (with different text - 'Go to page n') and it is useful, imho. if the pdf isn't mine, I'd rather not click a link without knowing where it points. (and, in fact, I'd rather not even if the pdf is mine because it is highly annoying that it always goes to page 1 if something is unresolved.) admittedly, the red box would make it rather more obtrusive ....
